# Changing keys in Python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to write a script that takes the keys in a dictionary and replaces them with the values in they map to in a CSV file. I'm having problems trying to find matching rows.

CSV file

```
QuestionKey,QuestionId
BASIC1,F4AB5C41-5BB2-41BD-AF7C-08E76BA05DCE
BASIC2,1E6D5B13-BDD2-43E7-9B74-36AD8C816A9C
```

Script:

```py
QUESTIONS_MAP = pd.read_csv('data/question_ids.csv', dtype=str)

def replace_questions_ids_with_keys(content: dict) -> dict:
    """Replace the question ids with the keys used in the decision response"""
    # LOGGER.info(QUESTIONS_MAP)
    for key, value in content.items():
        # LOGGER.info(QUESTIONS_MAP.QuestionId)
        # Find item QuestionKey for item in QUESTIONS_MAP where key in QuestionId
        question_key = list(filter(lambda x: key in x['QuestionId'], QUESTIONS_MAP))
        LOGGER.info(question_key)
        if question_key:
            content[QUESTIONS_MAP[key]] = value
            del content[key]
    return content
```

Example `content` dict:

```py
{'F4AB5C41-5BB2-41BD-AF7C-08E76BA05DCE': '', '1E6D5B13-BDD2-43E7-9B74-36AD8C816A9C': ''}
```

Runtime error:

```
2022-05-18 14:46:55,340 -  ERROR - string indices must be integers
```

Expected response:

```py
{'BASIC1': '', 'BASIC2': ''}
```

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Which indexing causing the error?

Comment: When you iterate over `QUESTIONS_MAP` in your filter, each `x` is a string (one of the keys from `['QuestionKey', 'QuestionId']`). So `x['QuestionId']` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Looks like `question_key = list(filter(lambda x: key in x['QuestionId'], QUESTIONS_MAP))`

Comment: Can you put an example of what you want to obtain?

Comment: So cut it down, give a [mre]. Note that's [explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) an anti-pattern anyway, write `[x for x in QUESTIONS_MAP if key in x['QuestionId']]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is more convenient to work with a dict than a dataframe. Thus,

```
# map question id -> question key
# squeeze tells pandas to produce a series when there's only one column
# index=1 tells it to use question id as an index
# finally, .to_dict() makes a dictionary out of the series
QUESTIONS_MAP = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', squeeze=True, index_col=1).to_dict()
```

Then, just use a dict comprehension:

```
content = {
    QUESTIONS_MAP[id_]: value 
    for id_, value in content.items() 
    if id_ in QUESTIONS_MAP
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Imho I think that using a dataframe (and pandas) is an overkill for what I can see.

Here's a simple solution:

```
import pandas as pd

QUESTIONS_MAP = pd.read_csv('data/question_ids.csv', dtype=str)

def replace_questions_ids_with_keys(content: dict) -> dict:
    """Replace the question ids with the keys used in the decision response"""
    result = {}
    for key, value in content.items():
        for i in range(len(QUESTIONS_MAP)):
            question_key = QUESTIONS_MAP.values[i][0]
            question_id = QUESTIONS_MAP.values[i][1]
            if question_id == key:
                result[question_key] = ""
    return result

my_dict = {'F4AB5C41-5BB2-41BD-AF7C-08E76BA05DCE': '', '1E6D5B13-BDD2-43E7-9B74-36AD8C816A9C': ''}


replace_questions_ids_with_keys(my_dict)
```